# jquery post() is not working in a dynamic form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm working on a simple form that is generated dynamically from a database, I came up with this simple form just to try it, but apparently works fine, but after submit on the same form the second time kinda holds the old value o.O

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


  function init(items,userId) {  
    var inputdata = $("#qty_"+items).val();
    var userId = userId;
    alert(inputdata);
    $("#form_"+items).live("submit", function() {
      $.post("test_query.php", { value:inputdata, userId:userId }, 
        function(data){
          $('#results').empty();
          alert(data);
        });

       return false;

      });

    };

</script>


<?php

for($i=1; $i <2; $i ++)
{
echo "
    <div>
    <form id='form_".$i."'>
        <input id='qty_".$i."' type='text' autocomplete='OFF' />
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" onclick=\"init(".$i.",2)\"/>
    </form>
    <script>

    </script>
    </div>
";
}
?>
</div>
```

UPDATE: Forgot to mention that the idea is not to refresh the page when submit. And the forms name/id are generated dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried e.stopPropagation() right at the top of your live submit? This sounds like a bubbling issue. If this doesnt solve it could you put up a live demo of the form somewhere?

Comment: make sure this is like this ` $("#form_"+items).live("submit", function(e) {` and then right after that put the `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: It's not about propagation, because "live" handlers are always on the body anyway.  It's the default action that must be prevented, and the `return false;` already there at the end of the handler will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do the same thing — manage the "submit" event handler for your form — in two ways, and it's just not really right.  You're generating the form HTML such that the "submit" button calls your "init" routine via the "click" handler.  What does that code do?  It sets up *another* event handler for "submit" events to the form. That handler will always use the parameters passed in the first time it was called.

You should *either* stick with the "onsubmit" handler, or (better) go with your instinct to use the jQuery "live" or "delegate" facilities to set up your handler.  Then your initialization code would go into a jQuery "ready" handler, and you'd completely leave off the "onsubmit" stuff:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').delegate('form', 'submit', function() {
      $.post("test_query.php", { value: $(this).find('input:text').val(), userId: 2 }, 
        function(data){
            $('#results').empty();
            alert(data);
            $('#results').html(data);
         }
       );
   });

   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah I used init function because each form is generated from a database, thats why, i coudnt think anything else of how to get the data from the right form(because the form name will be generated), but i didnt knew about delegate im reading right now :)

Comment: @mike the ".delegate()" thing is really the same sort of thing as ".live()", but it's just a little newer and better. The basic idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, sorry im very nooby at this, but I tried it and doenst show anything :( i think is because doenst know the id of the form?